# Scheduler - self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7, scheduler

I am using library scheduler for cron jobs in python. I want to send multiple arguments to the job to be scheduled. But I am getting follwing error:

```
File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/schedule/__init__.py", line 352, in do
self.job_func = functools.partial(job_func, *args, **kwargs)
TypeError: the first argument must be callable
```

Below is my code. I am using multithreading and want to schedule my thread tasks:

```
class myThread (threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, threadID, name, counter):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.threadID = threadID
    self.name = name
    self.counter = counter

def run(self):
    print "Starting " + self.name
    SomeClassInstance = SomeClass()
```

This didn't work:

```
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(phoneidLogger.getSplunkLogs(arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4))
```

Below also didn't help:

```
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(phoneidLogger.getSplunkLogs,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4)
```

Comment: Where is `job_func` defined?

Comment: Sorry it couldnt be formatted properly - Its **phoneidLogger.getSplunkLogs** where phoneidLogger is an instance of a class .

Comment: Here phoneidLogger is actually SomeClassInstance

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass a free function to your scheduler.

Bear in mind that

```
phoneidLogger.getSplunkLogs(arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

is equivalent to

```
PhoneLoggerClass.getSplunkLogs(phoneidLogger, arg1, arg2, arg3)
```

Knowing this, the right thing to do is pass in `phoneidLogger` as an argument to our scheduler.

```
schedule.every(10).minutes.do(PhoneLoggerClass.getSplunkLogs,
                              phoneidLogger,
                              arg1, arg2, arg3, arg4)
```

Comment: **schedule.every(10).minutes.do(splunkLogger.getSplunkLogs,phoneidLogger,arg1,arg2,arg3,arg4)** --- is exiting me from the thread. Its not executing.

Comment: Then you need to give a lot more detail in your question. Provide a [mcve].

Comment: **splunkLogger** is a class and 88pho‌​neidLogger is its instance and getSplunkLogs is the function.

Comment: `def run(self):
    print "Starting " + self.name
    SomeClassInstance = SomeClass() 
    schedule.every(10).minutes.do(splunkLogger.getSplunkLogs,pho‌​
    neidLogger,arg1,arg2‌​,arg3,arg4)
    print "Exiting " + self.name`

Comment: The above code doesn't execute the job. It seems like it ignores the schedule instruction.

Comment: **Show** us. "Seems like" isn't good enough on SO. Until you provide a [mcve], I'm voting to close the question.

Comment: Is there any other way to schedule a job in python2.7?